# 'guard' => false in newEntity() options not working in Cakephp4

Tags: php, cakephp-4.x

There's certainly something that I do wrong, but I can't use correctly the `guard` option of `newEntity()` method.

```
// Entity
class Bloc extends AbstractBloc
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => false // All fields are protected against mass assignment
    ];
}
```

`'guard' => false` doesn't allow to save my entity in this example :

```
// Controller
public function test()
{
    $entity = $this->Blocs->newEntity([
        'titre' => 'TEST ASSIGNEMENT',
        'rubrique_id' => 282,
        'description' => 'Content'
    ],  ['guard' => false]); // guard is false but nothing changes
    if ($this->Blocs->save($entity)) {
        return $this->redirect([...]);
    }
    else {
        die('save is false');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing changes"? The database is not updated? Or you inspect the entity immediately after the `newEntity` call (e.g. with xdebug or a debug($entity)`) and it's empty?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I mean `$entity` is not saved (with or without `'guard' => false`)

Comment: Have you checked whether there are errors in it? May be entirely unrelated to your `guard` setting. Add `debug($entity->getErrors());` in your `else` clause.

Comment: @GregSchmidt There's no error when I debug. Furthermore, when I set `'*' => true` in `$_accessible` the entity is well saved. That's why  `'guard'`seems not working to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option for `Table::newEntity()`, the `guard` option belongs to `Entity::set()`. The option for `newEntity()` is called `accessibleFields`.

```php
$entity = $this->Blocs->newEntity(
    [
        'titre' => 'TEST ASSIGNEMENT',
        'rubrique_id' => 282,
        'description' => 'Content',
    ],
    [
        'accessibleFields' => [
            // '*' => true
            'titre' => true,
            'rubrique_id' => true,
            'description' => true,
        ],
    ]
);
```

**https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html#changing-accessible-fields**

Comment: Thank you very much (once again ;) ndm). Strange, I had seen `$this->table->newEntity($data, ['validate' => false, 'guard' => false])` in the plugin FileStorage 4.0  (but never tried it...)...

Comment: @Oliv That's a possible bug then, you might want to to report that.